# How to move resizableUIView from its corner in Swift?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift2, resize

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0JTO.jpg)

I have created this screen using four rounded button on corners. and i need to resize view from all four button tapped event. on the button direction

This is what i need to do.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: are u able to see both attached image?

Comment: Please don't hide the substance of your question in links - your question should be self-contained, with links only for supplementary information that's not critical for the understanding of the question.  This way, the question retains its value, even if the linked-to site disappears.